# uninstalled nvidia drivers still showing in "additional drivers" tab

Tags: drivers, nvidia, purge

I tried literally everything to uninstall Nvidia drivers from Ubuntu 16.04 but they are somehow still showing in the "Additional drivers" tab.
What am I missing?
I'd like to purge them before trying to fix an issue and reinstall the right ones.

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cpuid                  16384  0
bnep                   20480  2
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
8250_dw                16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             204800  0
kvm                   589824  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
aesni_intel           188416  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
hci_uart              106496  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
serdev                 20480  1 hci_uart
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  1 hci_uart
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
idma64                 20480  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
virt_dma               16384  1 idma64
bluetooth             548864  11 hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
mei_me                 40960  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  2 intel_lpss_pci,intel_lpss_acpi
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
acpi_pad              180224  0
mac_hid                16384  0
industrialio           69632  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
parport_pc             32768  1
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  3 uas
nouveau              1650688  8
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    94208  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 nouveau
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
firewire_ohci          40960  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
drm                   360448  11 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  4
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
wmi                    24576  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  1 nouveau
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
pinctrl_intel          20480  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
```

Comment: You can use that to install it. But what makes you think, they are actually installed? Also add `lsmod` result.

Comment: They don't result installed except from the "Additional Drivers" tab in "Software and Updates". I can select them and "activate" them from there but they are not actually working.)
Added lsmod results in the main post!
Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: So the driver is not loaded, and I don't think it's installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional drivers panel will always show one driver or another and you cannot "uncheck" it to have no driver selected:

[image: Additional Drivers.png]

^^ Another interesting quirk is it displays "Unknown:Unknown". But what it really means is "Intel:Intel Microcode".